# XJC Task failing

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, weblogic12c, xjc

Trying to use XJC Ant Task and all the libraries reside in my Weblogic 12.2.1 installation. I am getting a below exception when running the anttask. I tried to change the version of eclipselink but not able to find a solution

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-50001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The class com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.factoryMethodOrConstructorRequired(JAXBException.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.finalizeProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:966)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:158)
```

Ant File as below

```
<project default="main" basedir=".">
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="C:\Weblogic\wlserver\server\lib" includes="**/weblogic.jar" />
    </path>

    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask" classpathref="build.classpath" />


    <echo message="calling the web services generation ant task: axis_bujava"/>
    <target name="main" >
        <compile-types/>

    </target>
    <macrodef name="compile-types">
        <sequential>
            <xjc destdir="C:\eclipse\workspace\Test\src" package="com.test.types">
                <ARG value="-npa" />
                <schema dir="C:\eclipse\workspace\Test\schema" includes="*.xsd" />
            </xjc>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

Comment: You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you post the relevant code.

Comment: <xs:element name="Testing" type="TestingType">
 </xs:element>
 <xs:complexType name="TestingType">

  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="indicator" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>
                                    Required: True/False
     </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>                
   </xs:element>                
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

Comment: When i add the annotation tag, an exception is throw -Exception Description: The class com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
 - with linked exception:. If I remove annotation it works fine.

Comment: Apparently your classpath is bad. Check ANT sample projects [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/releases/tag/0.11.0) and rework your classpath. It is strange that you compile against your Weblogic lib classpath.